# Getting HttpURLConnection data back to List View Adapter

Tags: java, android, multithreading

This is driving me crazy.  I was forced by android to create a thread so that it did not lock the main thread.  Now I want to get that data back to the ListView Adapter that I created.  I googled the error but it is not clear how to adapt this code.  Thanks to any help you can give

```
public class Detail extends AppCompatActivity
{
ListView list;
ListViewAdapter listviewadapter;
List<CData> lstData = new ArrayList<CData>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.listview_main);
    list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
    listviewadapter = new ListViewAdapter(this, R.layout.listview_item, lstData);
    list.setAdapter(listviewadapter);

    // these work
    CData d1 = new CData("test1", "data1", "a");
    lstData.add(d1);

    CData d2 = new CData("test2", "data2", "a");
    lstData.add(d2);

    Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run(){
            try {
                URL url = new URL("http://testserver.com/getdata.php");
                HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
                connection.connect();
                InputStream inStream = null;
                inStream = connection.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader bReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inStream));
                String temp, response = "";
                while ((temp = bReader.readLine()) != null) {
                    response += temp;
                }

                // this is not working
                CData d4 = new CData("test3", response, "a");
                lstData.add(d4);
                listviewadapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                // this prints out to the log window
                System.out.println("---------------yesss--------" + response);

                // this does not work
                listviewadapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                // this does not work either
                listviewadapter.clear();
                listviewadapter.addAll(lstData);
                listviewadapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            }

            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                System.out.println("generic ex" + ex.toString());
            }
        }
    });
    thread.start();


    CData d3 = new CData("test4", "data4", "a");
    lstData.add(d3);
```

Error

```
CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
```

Comment: better use `asynchtask`

Comment: exactly, use AsyncTask. Call your task on OnStart event of activity.

Answer (score 1):

First of all don't use threads for network request.

Either use [**AsyncTask**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) or Http libraries like [**Retrofit**](https://github.com/square/retrofit) or [**volley**](https://github.com/google/volley) etc libraries. Because they provide batter implementation of Http web request and handling mechanism.

From your code this can be solution

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
     @Override
     public void run() {

        //UI updates
        // this does not work either
        listviewadapter.clear();
        listviewadapter.addAll(lstData);
        listviewadapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you should update UI on UI thread like this

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
     @Override
     public void run() {

//stuff that updates ui

            listviewadapter.clear();
            listviewadapter.addAll(lstData);
            listviewadapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }
});
```

Comment: hello, is this not already happening on line 23 in the above code?  I saw that example on another s.o. but not sure how it applys to this code

Comment: Thread just create background thread and you can not update ui in background thread

Answer (score 0):

Make your d4 variable global.
After your catch statement :-

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    lstData.add(d4);
                    listviewadapter.clear();
                    listviewadapter.addAll(lstData);
                    listviewadapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
}
```